# DeclarationError about event emit solidity 0.7

Tags: solidity

In solidity 0.7 contract, an event `tradeCompleted` is defined as:

```
event tradeCompleted(address _poster, string  _posterItemName, uint256 _posterItemID, address _bidder,  string _bidderItemName,  uint256 _bidderItemID, uint256 _value);
```

In contract function, the above event was called as:

```
emit tradeCompleted(poster, posterItemName, posterItemID, bidder,  bidderItemName, bidderItemID[bidder],  value);
```

`bidderItemID` is a mapping defined as:

```
 mapping (address => uint256) public bidderItemID;
```

However there is a compiling error about the emit:

[image]

Comment: what about uint256 vvv =  bidderItemID[bidder];  emit tradeCompleted(poster, posterItemName, posterItemID, bidder,  bidderItemName, vvv, value); ? does this work

Comment: No. I tried to get the ID out of mapping first and it still didn't work.

Comment: Okay you need to show more code :(